# Get a null parameter in action

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

i have an asp.net mvc4 application in which i have in an action `X` :

```
 impaire_target = u.Get_Impaire_List().Find(x => x.id_paire == identificateur);
 Session["id_paire"] = a;
 return RedirectToAction("Page2","Pages",impaire_target );
```

The action `Page2`

```
  public ActionResult Page2(Impaire impa)
        {
            try
            {
                User u = (User)Session["user"];
                if (u.Login == null) RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
            catch { return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home"); }
            if (impa == null)
            {
                return View();
            }
            return View(impa);
        }
```

the problem is that the parameters `impa` is always null . even i try to replace `return RedirectToAction("Page2","Pages",impaire_target );` by `return RedirectToAction("Page2","Pages",new{ impa=impaire_target} );` i got the same result.

What is the reasons of this problem?

Comment: Are you sure your impaire_target is not null and it has Impaire type? Method List<T>.Find returns default value for T if matched object is not found.

Comment: yes i verified it isn't null

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use ModelBinding with `RedirectToAction`, so no complex type as anonymous object. Try to convert the object to a `RouteValueDictionary`:

```
return RedirectToAction("Page2", "Pages", new RouteValueDictionary(impaire_target));
```

Side note: you always have to *return* the `RedirectToAction`, or it won't work.

Answer (score 1):

You should use Session or TempData for passing complex data between controller actions. [Here](http://www.devcurry.com/2012/05/what-is-aspnet-mvc-tempdata.html#.UlRnnlDIvjk) it is described in details.

Example:

```
impaire_target = u.Get_Impaire_List().Find(x => x.id_paire == identificateur);
TempData["impa"] = impaire_target;
Session["id_paire"] = a;
return RedirectToAction("Page2","Pages");
```

The action `Page2`

```
    public ActionResult Page2()
    {
        Impaire impa = TempData["impa"] as Impaire;
        try
        {
            User u = (User)Session["user"];
            if (u.Login == null) RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
        catch { return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home"); }
        if (impa == null)
        {
            return View();
        }
        return View(impa);
    }
```